# Call function from UITableViewCell from in ViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to call function **deleteButtonShowHide**, which is in TeamsCell, from TeamsVC, when **plusBtnTapped**. I am trying to figure it out with **protocol TeamsVCDelegate**, but it doesn't work( It works vice versa for me. But I do not know how to implement something like **cell.teamsCellDelegate = self**

**TeamsCell**

```
import UIKit

protocol TeamsCellDelegate {
    func deleteCell()
}



class TeamsCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var teamNameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteButton: UIButton!
    var teamsCellDelegate: TeamsCellDelegate?
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    
    func updateCell(team: team) {
        teamNameLbl.text = team.name
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func deleteButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        debugPrint("delet tapped")
        //deleteButtonShowHide()
        findAndDeleteTeam()
        teamsCellDelegate?.deleteCell()
    }
    
    func findAndDeleteTeam() {
        for i in 0...teams.count - 1 {
            if teams[i].name == teamNameLbl.text {
                teams.remove(at: i)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteButtonShowHide(){
        if teams.count < 3 {deleteButton.isHidden = true}
        if teams.count > 2 {deleteButton.isHidden = false}
    }
    
}

extension TeamsCell: TeamsVCDelegate {
    func deleteButtonSH() {
        debugPrint("XXX")
        deleteButtonShowHide()
    } 
}
```

**TeamsVC**

```
import UIKit

protocol TeamsVCDelegate {
    func deleteButtonSH()
}

class TeamsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   
    @IBOutlet weak var plusBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var teamsTable: UITableView!
    var teamsVCDelegate: TeamsVCDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        teamsTable.delegate = self
        teamsTable.dataSource = self
        teamsTable.rowHeight = 55
        teamsTable.isScrollEnabled = false
        teamsTable.backgroundColor = nil
        teamsTable.separatorStyle = .none
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return teams.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TeamsCell") as? TeamsCell {
            cell.updateCell(team: teams[indexPath.row])
            cell.teamsCellDelegate = self
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    @IBAction func plusBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        plusBtnHide()
        addTeam()
        teamsTable.reloadData()
        teamsVCDelegate?.deleteButtonSH()
        print(teams)
    }
    
    func plusBtnShow() {
        if teams.count < 5 {plusBtn.isHidden = false}
    }
    
    func plusBtnHide() {
        if teams.count == 4 { plusBtn.isHidden = true}
    }
    
}

extension TeamsVC: TeamsCellDelegate {
    func deleteCell() {
        self.teamsTable.reloadData()
        self.plusBtnShow()
    }
}
```

Comment: where is that `teams` array coming from? There is not instance of such array in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `deleteButtonShowHide` function when you are loading/setting up a cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TeamsCell") as? TeamsCell {
        cell.updateCell(team: teams[indexPath.row])
        cell.deleteButtonShowHide()  // <-- HERE
        cell.teamsCellDelegate = self
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

---

By the way, your cell should not contain such logic in the first place. It should depend on some data model object which then should be used to setup your cell correctly (show/hide UI elements, etc.).

Comment: Why this logic is bad? I just use it to show/hide the delete button. It is related to teams of the game, so the minimum team amount is two and the max is 5. First of all, I tried trialswipeAction, but it doesn't fit my UI/UX.

Comment: I would not call the logic "bad", everything is fine with it as long as it works, but if you think about it, in the future, when your project grows, it is going to be harder and harder to maintain it, because all the logic is scattered between different parts of the codebase, ideally it should be centralised somewhere and UI should only react to those data changes and not check anything by itself. Just some food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify by setting the button show/hide when computing the number of row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if teams.count < 5 {plusBtn.isHidden = false}
    if teams.count == 4 { plusBtn.isHidden = true}
    return teams.count
}
```

And set the delebutton visibility when creating the cell :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TeamsCell") as? TeamsCell {
        cell.updateCell(team: teams[indexPath.row])
        // cell.teamsCellDelegate = self
        cell.deleteButton.isHidden = (teams.count < 3)
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

So no need for delegate and cell does not have to know about the model (teams)